# Loading low-res version of high-res image from the server (non-javascript solution)

Tags: html, css, django, image

Imagine there's a 10MB image file residing in the static folder of your web application.

If you loaded it in an HTML file with something like this: `<img src="static/image.png"></img>`, the entire 10MB would load for the user requesting the image.

But what if the tag was `<img src="static/image.png" height="10" width="10"></img>`? I.e. it resized the image to 10px by 10px (presumably much smaller than 10MB). Would the user's end still be loading the entire 10MB? Personally, I think the user would still load 10MB. Please correct me if I'm wrong. That's my first question.

If I'm right though, what are some strategies to dynamically thumbnail this kind of an image such that the **file size loaded at the user's end** gets reduced too (short of actually storing a separate thumbnail file for each image on the server). Assume it's a **non-javascript environment**, that the webserver is nginx, and the web application is built in Django (if it matters).

Is storing separate thumbnails the only way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes the user has to download the full 10Mb.
2. There are some nice django apps to handle automatic thubmnail generation. 
   I use [`django-versatileimagefield`](http://django-versatileimagefield.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). There you can easily implement different thumbnail sizes.

   ```
   from django.db import models

   class ExampleModel(models.Model):
       image = models.ImageField(
       'Image',
       upload_to='images/'
   )

   >>> from someapp.models import ExampleModel
   >>> instance = ExampleModel.objects.all()[0]
   >>> instance.image.thumbnail['200x200'].url
   '/media/__sized__/images/test-image-thumbnail-200x200.jpg'

   # or in templates:
   <img src="{{ instance.image.thumbnail.200x200 }}" />
   ```

Answer (score 2):

1: yes, the user would download the large 10MB and the browser would resize (probably using shady resize algorithms of it's choice)

2: I would generate the thumbnail my self at the time of upload and store it. If you generate it on the fly it could potentially be slow and you'd end up choosing a crappy algorithm, as well as using to much cpu server side.

Answer (score 1):

Yes even if you resize the image in HTML, the image still will be 10mb. 
I would also create different size thumbnails and upload on server, rather than server doing the resizing.
You can also check the following URL for alternate options
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/responsive-images-done-right-guide-picture-srcset/